# 400 Bad Request error during Flask file upload?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

This is the view function used to generate a file upload form and process it (yes this comes directly from the [Flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/fileuploads/)):

```
transaction_blueprint = Blueprint(
    "transaction", __name__, template_folder="../templates", url_prefix="/transactions"
)

@transaction_blueprint.route("/upload", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def upload_select_file():
    print(request.method)
    if request.method == "POST":
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if "file" not in request.files:
            flash("No file part")
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files.get("file")
        # if user does not select file, browser also
        # submit an empty part without filename
        if file.filename == "":
            flash("No selected file")
            return redirect(request.url)
        # allowed_file is defined elsewhere
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join("/tmp", filename))
            return jsonify({"success": True})
    return """
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Upload new File</title>
    <h1>Upload new File</h1>
    <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <input type=file name=file>
      <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
    <p>%s</p>
    """ % "<br>".join(os.listdir("/tmp",))
```

Upon submitting the form from `http://localhost:8000/transactions/upload`, I receive the 400 bad request error. I am testing with a simple text file that is about 15kb in size. As far as I can tell, the HTML is well formed:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="file">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

I've searched for two days and learned this error occurs when the file input's `name` attribute is not found in the Flask view endpoint. I handle for that using `request.files.get("file")`. Further In my case, upon submitting the form, the method is not being reached (server log does not even print "`POST`"). This makes sense as the 400 is a client error but still...

Is there something with using Blueprints that's breaking this? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The `form` has no action - what is causing it to go to `/upload`? Try something like `<form method="post" action="{{ url_for('transactions.upload_select_file') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: Without an action, the form defaults to sending to the same endpoint the form is on. I should add, including the action still fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the csrf token did it...

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
```